# Wordpress installed on subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I want to add a blogging area to my portfolio site here:

www.ryanpays.com

I have set up a subdomain of:

www.blog.ryanpays.com

And mapped this to www.ryanpays.com/wordpress/

When i hit the subdomain i get a 404 error and am not sure why.

I installed Wordpress with a CGI script bundled with my hosting which seemed to work as you can navigate to the test page.

Comment: How are you remapping it.  Have you considered setting up a virtual domain for www.blog.ryanpays.com and hosting it from there.

Comment: BTW, I think there's a typo on your home page, Wesbites is probably not what you meant :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm) to set-up a subdomain. If you still have trouble you can post your configuration, like your VirtualHost entry if you're using Apache.